# ApplicationWillResignActive in task switcher and message alert

Tags: ios, swift

The problem is I'm trying to protect my app data so whenever enter task switcher, the app screen will be blurred and the code is executed in `applicationWillResignActive` method. But when I first launch my app, It would ask for permission to enable notification and camera, the message alert appeared and blurred the background, `applicationWillResignActive` method is executed.

So anyway for me to separate these two events?